# Using Identity with custom property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using Asp.Net Identity in webforms application. What I'm trying to achieve is to check in the database if the user `IsActive` if true sign in and if false display error message. If I set a breakpoint and check the `IsActive` value it's exactly as in the database. My Database column is of data type `Bit`. The problem I'm having is I can't display the error message to the end user. My code is below

```
if (IsValid)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager();
        ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (user != null && user.IsActive == true)
        {
            IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
            Response.Redirect("~/SecurePage.aspx"); //Redirect to a different page once user has logged in

            if(user.IsActive == false)
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Sorry you no longer have access"; //This error message never displays
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password."; //This message displays even when user is not active
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

If the user is not active they can't sign in which works but it displays the wrong error message. I think it might be my `if` logic. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Comment: don't use (user.IsActive == false) check inside the (user != null && user.IsActive == true). Make them sepearte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code is that the statement `if(user.IsActive == false)` will *never* get executed, because the first `if` statement will be true only when user is active. You need to tweak the code a little bit to make it work properly.

```
if (user != null)
{
     if (user.IsActive)
     {
         IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
         Response.Redirect("~/SecurePage.aspx"); //Redirect to a different page once user has logged in
     }
     else
     {
         FailureText.Text = "Sorry you no longer have access"; //This error message never displays
         ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
     }
}
```

Please also note that I changed `user.IsActive == true` to `user.IsActive`. Comparing a `bool` to true in such a way is redundant in an `if` statement condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your check for `if(user.IsActive == false)` is unreachable, because you are redirecting the user just before you would check for it. Move this if clause out of the parent if-block:

```
    if (user != null && user.IsActive == true)
    {
        IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
        Response.Redirect("~/SecurePage.aspx"); //Redirect to a different page once user has logged in

    }
    else if(user != null && user.IsActive == false) 
    {
        FailureText.Text = "Sorry you no longer have access"; 
        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password."; //This message displays even when user is not active
        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect("~/SecurePage.aspx");` will redirect to another page and  the execution of the current page will be terminated. So the code after [`Response.Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx) is not executed.

You could move it to the `else`:

```
if(user.IsActive == false)
{
    FailureText.Text = "Sorry you no longer have access"; //This error message never displays
    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
}
else
    Response.Redirect("~/SecurePage.aspx"); //Redirect to a different page once user has logged in
```